# Allocate a vector to a subset of an R dataframe column

Tags: r

I'm looking to create a function which creates a random number column where the numbers generated are bounded per category. For example, for cat = "2011", I'd like the random numbers generated to be between 1 and 2 and for cat = "2012", I'd like the random numbers generated to be between 3 and 4.

I've written a function which creates a random vector and then tries to allocate the values in that vector to the random variable column.

```
controlled_rvf <- function(df,cat,delta=1, width = 1,desc = FALSE, sig = 3)
{

  df$rv <- NA
  cat_list <- unique(df[[cat]])
  cat_list <- sort(cat_list,decreasing = desc)
  min = 0
  for(i in 1:length(cat_list))
  {
    min = min+delta
    n <- nrow(df[df[[cat]]==cat_list[i],])
    df[df[[cat]]==cat_list[i],"rv"] <- 
      round(runif(nrow(df[df[[cat]]==cat_list[i],]),min,min+width),sig)
  }
  return(df)
}
```

In this function, the allocation line

```
df[df[[cat]]==cat_list[i],"rv"] <- 
          round(runif(nrow(df[df[[cat]]==cat_list[i],]),min,min+width),sig)
```

results in truncation of the RHS vector to datatype: logical

I would appreciate any way to bypass this in R. I would not prefer to loop every row because that would extremely performance intensive

Example: 
For a dataframe shown below:

```
year    v1
2012    1.621
2012    1.106
2012    1.672
2012    1.797
2012    1.679
2012    1.611
2013    1.798
2013    1.158
2013    1.224
2013    1.061
2013    1.083
2013    1.695
2014    1.702
2014    1.066
2014    1.493
2014    1.993
2014    1.2
2014    1.149
```

I want to create a random variable **rv** bounded by each category (year in this case):

```
year    v1      rv
2012    1.621   1.86
2012    1.106   1.137
2012    1.672   1.507
2012    1.797   1.917
2012    1.679   1.618
2012    1.611   1.192
2013    1.798   3.346
2013    1.158   3.792
2013    1.224   3.492
2013    1.061   3.742
2013    1.083   3.04
2013    1.695   3.642
2014    1.702   5.877
2014    1.066   5.757
2014    1.493   5.272
2014    1.993   5.214
2014    1.2     5.249
2014    1.149   5.424
```

Comment: Can you please present a reproducible example with the expected results starting from an input?

Comment: i don’t get what you mean “bounded by the year.” How do you want them bounded? Your example output doesn’t follow the bounding example you give in your question.

Comment: For the category 2012, the random variable should be between a lower bound of 1 and upper bound of 2, similarly, for 2013, the rv should be between a lower bound of 4 and upper bound of 4. Hope that explains.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved the random number variable problem by creating a column within the dataframe to store the bounds. I still do not know how to allocate a vector to a subset of a column, though.

```
sig <- 5
width <- 1
df$bound <- (year-2010)*2 - 1
df$rv <- round(runif(nrow(df),df$bound,df$bound+width),sig)
```

It solves my problem, but bound creation is still a fairly manual process.